# Fill FDQuery/Dataset with stored DB infos from XML file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firedac

I have an XML file where I store database infos (TableName, Records etc) Are there any way to load Records to a Query or Dataset from the file? I want to change TablaName parameters and after I want to fill the database with Table Records. Thanks for the answers!

My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Data>
  -<Table Sql="Select * from VAT_RATE " MinimumCapacity="50" EnforceConstraints="False" TabID="0" SourceID="1" SourceName="VAT_RATE" Name="FDQuery">
   -<ColumnList>
     <Column SourceID="1" SourceName="VAT_RATE_ID" Name="VAT_RATE_ID" OriginColName="VAT_RATE_ID" OriginTabName="VAT_RATE" OInKey="True" OInWhere="True" OInUpdate="True" Base="True" Searchable="True" DataType="Int32"/>
     <Column SourceID="2" SourceName="BEGINS" Name="BEGINS" OriginColName="BEGINS" OriginTabName="VAT_RATE" OInWhere="True" OInUpdate="True" Base="True" Searchable="True" DataType="Date" OAllowNull="True" AllowNull="True"/>
     <Column SourceID="3" SourceName="ENDS" Name="ENDS" OriginColName="ENDS" OriginTabName="VAT_RATE" OInWhere="True" OInUpdate="True" Base="True" Searchable="True" DataType="Date" OAllowNull="True" AllowNull="True"/>
     <Column SourceID="4" SourceName="NAME" Name="NAME" OriginColName="NAME" OriginTabName="VAT_RATE" OInWhere="True" OInUpdate="True" Base="True" Searchable="True" DataType="AnsiString" SourceSize="20" Size="20"/>
     <Column SourceID="5" SourceName="ACCOUNT" Name="ACCOUNT" OriginColName="ACCOUNT" OriginTabName="VAT_RATE" OInWhere="True" OInUpdate="True" Base="True" Searchable="True" DataType="AnsiString" SourceSize="20" Size="20"/>
     <Column SourceID="6" SourceName="KEY" Name="KEY" OriginColName="KEY" OriginTabName="VAT_RATE" OInWhere="True" OInUpdate="True" Base="True" Searchable="True" DataType="Currency" SourceScale="2" SourcePrecision="9" Scale="2" Precision="9"/>
     <Column SourceID="7" SourceName="D_EFAULT" Name="D_EFAULT" OriginColName="D_EFAULT" OriginTabName="VAT_RATE" OInWhere="True" OInUpdate="True" Base="True" Searchable="True" DataType="Int16"/>
     <Column SourceID="8" SourceName="count_ID" Name="count_ID" OriginColName="count_ID" OriginTabName="VAT_RATE" OInWhere="True" OInUpdate="True" Base="True" Searchable="True" DataType="Int32"/>
   </ColumnList>
   <ConstraintList/>
    <ViewList/>
   -<RowList>
     -<Row RowState="Unchanged" RowID="0">
       <Original count_ID="14" D_EFAULT="0" KEY="20" ACCOUNT="20%" NAME="20%" ENDS="20090630" BEGINS="20051001" VAT_RATE_ID="1"/>
      </Row>
     -<Row RowState="Unchanged" RowID="1">
       <Original count_ID="14" D_EFAULT="0" KEY="18" ACCOUNT="18%" NAME="18%" BEGINS="20040101" VAT_RATE_ID="3"/>
     </Row>
   </RowList>
  </Table>
</Data>
```

In the example TablneName is ... SourceName="VAT_RATE"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this seems to be to modify the `SaveTXML` method in my answer to your earlier q ([Append TFDMemTable data into one XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137698/append-tfdmemtable-data-into-one-xml-file)) as shown below and add a `LoadFromXML` method.

The reason for modifying the `SaveToXML` is that an FDQuery requires the `Manager` node of the XML that it generates when doing a save, and the earlier version of my `SaveToXML` stripped it out.

In the `LoadFromXML`, the query + data which is loaded it determined by this statement

```
    Node := NodeList.item[0];
```

`NodeList` is the list of child nodes of the saved XML's top-level document element, and`item[0]` is simply the first one of these nodes (they are numbered 0..`NodeList.length` - 1).  So to load a different one, you could set the `item[]` number to suit.  Depending on how familiar you are with XML XPath queries, there are various other ways to select the XML node whose query + data you reload, but XPath is a completely different topic.

Btw, make sure you delete or rename any version of the XML file which was saved prior to making the change to `SaveToXML` because the previous version is incompatible with the`LoadFromXML`.

Code:

```
const
  scSavedData = 'D:\delphi\code\firedac\SavedData.Xml';
  scSavedSingleQuery = 'D:\delphi\code\firedac\SavedSingleQuery.Xml';
  scSavedDataXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Data/>';

procedure TForm1.LoadFromXML(FDQuery: TFDQuery);
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  XmlDoc : IXmlDOMDocument;
  NodeList: IXmlDomNodeList;
  Node: IXmlDomNode;
  Element : IXmlDomElement;
begin
  if FDQuery.Active then
    FDQuery.Close;
  SS := TStringStream.Create;
  XmlDoc := CoDomDocument.Create;
  try
    XmlDoc.load('file://' + scSavedData);
    NodeList := XmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
    Node := NodeList.item[0];
    SS.WriteString(Node.xml);
    FDQuery.LoadFromStream(SS, sfXML);
  finally
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveToXML(FDQuery: TFDQuery);
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  XmlDoc1,
  XMlDoc2 : IXMLDOMDocument2;
  nDestination : IXmlDomNode;
  eDestination : IXmlDomElement;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create;
  XmlDoc1 := CoDomDocument.Create;
  try
    FDQuery.SaveToStream(SS, sfXML);
    XmlDoc1.loadXML(SS.DataString);
    Memo1.Lines.Text := SS.DataString;

    XmlDoc2 := CoDomDocument.Create;
    if FileExists(scSavedData) then begin
      XmlDoc2.load(scSavedData)
    end
    else begin
      XmlDoc2.loadXML(scSavedDataXML);
    end;
    nDestination := XmlDoc1.DocumentElement.cloneNode(True) as IXmlDomNode;
    XmlDoc2.documentElement.appendChild(nDestination);
    eDestination := nDestination as IXmlDomElement;
    eDestination.setAttribute('Sql', FDQuery.SQL.Text);

    Memo1.Lines.Text := XmlDoc2.documentElement.Xml;
    XmlDoc2.save(scSavedData);
  finally
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;
```